# Run a SP D workflow each day - with step by step

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, updatelistitems

I want a SP D workflow to run each day, that will update a SPO List.

Is there any articles that gives the step by step process to achieve this? I found many posts but stuck at somewhere

environment: am using SP online.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways for your reference:

1. use Information Management Policy-Retention rule to trigger the workflow like:
   [image]
2. create a Windows Scheduled Task to trigger the workflow daily.

[Sharepoint Online Powershell script to run a list workflow](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0e14cb97-d8d6-42a5-8825-f3a4f8e434a5/sharepoint-online-powershell-script-to-run-a-list-workflow?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

[How to Automate PowerShell Scripts with Task Scheduler](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/)

Comment: client doesnt have subscribed to the O 365 SPO IMR serv9oce.-Azure info,protetion service. so that rules out. how to run the  
 sp o powershell ?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Flow witch runs once a day, and starts your workflow by rest call to SP. 
http://www.benprins.net/2016/12/30/sharepoint-2013-workflow-start-a-workflow-using-a-rest-call/